# How to Create a Nested List view in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, list-view, aura, account-teams

Actually I am trying to Create a list view in Lightning which will show me list of accounts and associated Account Team members under them. How can I do it ?

Comment: Hi Rutvij. Your question appears to be asking for other people to write code for you. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions about real problems or errors with our code. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you

Comment: @Himanshu Well said.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aura:iteration inside an aura:iteration - in the markup, while returning an account list (nested with Account Team members) in the apex controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**aura:iteration**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_iteration.htm) and display data accordingly.